# c++11, salvaging a set

Tags: c++, set, move-semantics

Is there a clean way of moving the elements of a set out of it ? Something like:

```
set<A> s {...};
vector<A> v;
for (const A& a : s)
    v.push_back(move(const_cast<A&>(a)));
s.clear(); //undefined behavior?
```

Comment: I have a felling anything that modifies the elements of the set is UB as you break the ordering.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/move_iterator

Comment: too bad std::set<T>::erase doesn't return T&&

Comment: @Caleth `set::iterator` has been a constant bidirectional iterator since C++11. You can't move from the elements it points--they're `const`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++11, no. The move you're doing is undefined behavior.

In C++17, yes, with [`extract()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/extract):

```
for (auto it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); ) {
    v.push_back(std::move(s.extract(it++).value()));
}
s.clear();
```